# Appending Array Together in nodeJS

Tags: arrays, node.js

I have an array:

```
var arr = [
  "apple",
  "banana",
  "cherry"
];
```

How can I create a multi-line string, as such:

```
var foo = 
"
apple
banana
cherry
"
```

I want to start a new line with each element of the array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Array.join() like this:

```
var arr = [
  "apple",
  "banana",
  "cherry"
];

var foo = arr.join("\n");
```